# Method call according to derived class type

Tags: c++

Hello i would like to see if there is any way to resolve the problem i am having, i am going to use chess pieces as an example here. Let's say i have a base class called piece and 3 derived classes called pawn, knight and bishop. What i want to do is to check for each piece the validity of a specific move made, so i would write something like this

```
class piece{
    protected:
    ......
    
    public:
    .....
};

class pawn{
    
    public:
    bool move_is_legit(int displacement){....}
    ....
};

class knight{
    
    public:
    bool move_is_legit(int displacement){....}
    ....
};

class bishop{
   
    public:
    bool move_is_legit(int displacement){....}
    ....
};
```

For each derived class the move_is_legit function is different as different moves are valid for each piece. Now say i have a vector of pieces (could be knight pawn or bishop). I also have a a function defined like this to get the a piece from a specific location

```
 piece get_piece(int location){return Board[location];}
```

So is there a way to use this function and write something like

```
piece moving_piece = game.get_piece(loc);
moving_piece.move_is_legit();
```

And have the correct move_is_legit function called according to the derived class type? Thank you in advance.

Comment: Tip: `const piece& get_piece(int location) const { return Board[location]; } ` This avoids making unnecessary copies of the pieces.

Comment: Looks like you need a `virtual` function here. Doesn't the "legit move" function also need to know the state of the board?

Comment: The quick answer is yes - read up on virtual functions as well as pointers and references. You'll find more explained in a good book / learning resource than what you'll get written in an answer here.

Comment: [Generally recommended learning resources](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/388242/the-definitive-c-book-guide-and-list)